# limit of a holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, holomorphic-functions

Let $x\in [a,b]$ with $a<b$ real numbers.

Let Log be the principle determination of the complex logarithm with argument in $]-\pi,\pi[$.

I try to calculate $\lim_{z\to x, Im(z)>0} f(z)= Log(\frac{z-a}{z-b})$.

What I did
$f$ is well defined on  $ [a,b]$.
$Log(\frac{z-a}{z-b})  = |\frac{z-a}{z-b}| + i Arg(\frac{z-a}{z-b})$.

The modulus and the argument are continuous functions so:

$\lim_{z\to x, Im(z)>0} f(z)=-\frac{x-a}{x-b} + i Arg(\frac{x-a}{x-b})$

My question is about $Arg(\frac{x-a}{x-b})$, is it simply $\pi$ because it it a negative real?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: Thank you! in that case, do we have also  $\lim_{z\to x, Im(z)<0} f(z)=-\frac{x-a}{x-b} + i \pi$ ?